# Replace CodeIgniter Query builder

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-builder

I'm trying to make my own implementation of the Query builder in codeigniter. 
Basicly I would like to add some function and all the provided function. Something like :

```
$this-db->from('myTable')
        ->where('id', 1)
        ->custom_where('name', 'customsValues')
        ->get()
```

There values are irrelevent here.
I've already built a class that extends en current `CI_DB_query_builder` but I have no idea where to set my class to be used as the primary query builder. I've try to look up similar problem on google but could not find anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer to my question. However, any other good answer is welcome since mine is not the prettiest.

First let me walk you through what I was trying to do. 
I wanted to use [Tightenco's collect library](https://github.com/tightenco/collect) to use collection rather than array. This way I could use more intuitive chain array function:
 `$this->db->from('...')->results()->map(function($items) { ... })->toArray();`

Then, i wanted to have my own function, such as `where_if`.

I started by making my own query builder class that extended from `CI_DB_query_builder`. I have an example below:

```
<?php
require BASEPATH . 'database/DB_query_builder.php';


class CustomQueryBuilder extends CI_DB_query_builder {
    public function where_if($where, $value, $condition) : CustomQueryBuilder {
        if($condition) {
            $this->where($where, $value);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function results() : \Tightenco\Collect\Support\Collection {
        return \Tightenco\Collect\Support\Collection::make($this->get()->result_array());
    }
}
```

To link this class as the main Querybuilder, I had to change it in the file `system/database/DB.php`. 
I changed the path of the `require_once` in line 171 :

```
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/QueryBuilder/CustomQueryBuilder.php');
```

I also changed the alias class on line 182

```
class CI_DB extends CustomQueryBuilder { }
```

Please note that this is on codeigniter v3.0.6, your line number may differ.

Now, i needed to import some function so the autocomplete on PHPStorm would still point to my custom querybuilder, because once i used the function `from`, it returned a `CI_DB_query_builder` object. 
Here is how I imported the function I used the most.

```
/**
 * Nothing changed here, for autocompletion only
 * @param mixed $from
 * @return $this|CI_DB_query_builder
 */
public function from($from) {
    parent::from($from);
    return $this;
}
```

I really hope this helps people that are trying the same thing. If you got any feedback on this project, please let me know !

Comment: `change it in the file system/database/DB.php` in CI typically you can place a class replacing CI with MY in the `app/core` folder to override it, so instead of `CustomQueryBuilder` (or the original `CI_DB_query_builder`) your class would be `MY_DB_query_builder` etc. And then CI will use the MY version instead.  I use a heavily modified CI2  install, doing it this way...

Comment: Sure, it's important because if you edit the system files, the next time you update your CI install you run the very real risk of losing that change.  Which may or may not be obvious from light testing.  In other words you could update CI sometime in the future and then months later find a part of you site broken and realize you lost those code changes, something to be avoided if possible as when that happens, not only do you lose your code change (so you have no example of what you did), you may not remember exactly were or what it was.

Comment: Unfortunaly, Because of the way the querybuilder instantiated, it is not possible to use @ArtisticPhoenix Solutions.